# Can zinc nitride be used as light emitting material?

Tags: optics, material-science, semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

I cannot manage to find any journal papers about the applicability of zinc nitride as active layer of an light emitting diode (LED). But certain papers got mention that zinc nitride with a direct bandgap can be fabricated with potential applications in optoelectronics.

Can anyone give me some opinions on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle yes. But to make a good $\text{Zn}_3\text{N}_2$ homojunction LED you need the capability to incorporating both p-type and n-type dopants (normally oxide materials are naturally n-type) which might not be possible.

From what I have read, this material has been proposed as a way of making p-type ZnO (which is naturally n-type) by a post growth annealing step. This means that via $\text{Zn}_3\text{N}_2$ you maybe able to make a p-ZnO/n-ZnO homojunction LED.

More info here, http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2013/ra/c3ra46558f.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So currently there is not any report on change the type of conductivity of zinc nitride adding suitable dopants?

Comment: There is currently a lot of research going on into $\text{Zn}_3\text{N}_2$ because many of the fundamental properties are not well understood. But like other oxide semiconductor $\text{Zn}_3\text{N}_2$ is naturally n-type (http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2180541). **If** you find a p-type dopant then you could offset the natural tendency towards n-type conductivity. But think like other oxide semiconductors they can only be made weakly p-type. I don't think anybody has tried. Like I said before the interested is using $\text{Zn}_3\text{N}_2$ as a stepping stone to make p-type ZnO.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently published a paper on Zn3N2 nanocrystals (http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/tc/c4tc00403e#!divAbstract). The material appears to have a direct band gap around 1eV and makes nice nanophosphors so if you can work out how to p and n dope it I am sure you could make an LED.